# Google App Engine PHP App : Too Many Redirects

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml, app.yaml

When deploying a simple PHP App to GAE, I always get "EER-TOO-MANY-REDIRECTS".

My main index.php is only there to redirect to src/index.php where my "Hello World" statement is

[image]

My simple app works on localhost just fine, and would work on GAE if I remove the redirection, and directly put the Hello World in the root index.php not src/index/php

I believe I need to configure my app.yaml to accommodate this, but I am not sure what should be done!

My Directory is as follows

[image]

app.yaml

```
runtime: php74
# Defaults to "serve index.php" and "serve public/index.php". Can be used to
# serve a custom PHP front controller (e.g. "serve backend/index.php") or to
# run a long-running PHP script as a worker process (e.g. "php worker.php").
#
# entrypoint: serve index.php
```

root index.php

```
<?php
//echo 'hello world!';
header('Location: src/index.php');
?>
```

hello world statement in src/index.php

```
<?php

echo 'hello world!';
```

Comment: Please do not post code as images, write the code for every file. On the other hand, I'm not an expert with PHP but maybe the `index.php` it's redirecting to itself instead of the desired one?

Comment: On the other hand, whats the purpose of redirecting from one index to another? Why you don't simply serve the needed index?